# Customising swap() plugin to animate background color

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate, background-color

Can anybody suggest how to make the swapped boxes change background color on click when using the below plugin?

http://www.vertstudios.com/blog/swap-jquery-plugin/ (see demo)

I'm not sure how to link to plugins in JSFiddle so can't demonstrate unfortunately.

The methods animate the position of all boxes affecting only those where the position has changed. I'm trying to add a method that animates the background color similarly but without success.

I don't think this is possible without customising the plugin but I could be wrong.

---

Update:

Thanks Johan. I should have said that I actually need the background color to animate back to default after the swap. I tried your solution already with the below amendment. As you can see, it behaves inconsistently. I think the way to do this properly is to customise the fakeFloat method.

```
$("#swapTrigger").click(function()
{
var index1 = $('input:radio[name=index1]:checked').val();
var index2 = $('input:radio[name=index2]:checked').val();
boxes = $(boxes).swap(index1,index2);

var $box1 = $('.box').eq(index1);
var $box2 = $('.box').eq(index2);

var randomHex = '#fc0';

$box1.animate({ backgroundColor: "#fc0" }, 300);
$box2.animate({ backgroundColor: "#fc0" }, 300);


$(boxes).fakeFloat({margin: 10, offset: 20, speed: 300}).each(function()


{
    $box1.animate({ backgroundColor: "#fff" }, 300);
    $box2.animate({ backgroundColor: "#fff" }, 300);
    $(this).html($(this).getIndexOf(boxes));
});
```

Comment: And what happens when you try to animate the backgroundcolor? Is the problem that the color isnt chancging? Or doesnt your event fire at the right time?

Comment: The code iterates though and animates all boxes so the color changes for all of them - not just the ones to be swapped. I think the solution is to pass the default backlgroundcolor value to the fakeFloat method where all boxes are animated. Except change the backgroundcolor value of the index of the boxes to be swapped. I just can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: I suppose that you are passing the indexes of which elements you want to swap, right? And thats the same boxes that you want the color swapped on?

Comment: Please have a look at my answer below

Comment: Thanks Johan - I've replied above.

Answer (score 0):

1. Include minified color plugin in order to anmiate bgcolors:

   http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/jquery.animate-colors-min.js
2. Try this in the onclick event

   ```
   $("#swapTrigger").click(function()
   {
       var index1 = $('input:radio[name=index1]:checked').val();
       var index2 = $('input:radio[name=index2]:checked').val();
       boxes = $(boxes).swap(index1,index2);

       var $box1 = $('.box').eq(index1);
       var $box2 = $('.box').eq(index2);

       var randomHex = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);

       $box1.animate({ backgroundColor: randomHex }, 200);

       $(boxes).fakeFloat({margin: 10, offset: 20, speed: 300}).each(function()
       {
           $(this).html($(this).getIndexOf(boxes));
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks Johan - I've replied above

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've pretty much cracked this, I think.

All I need now is to tidy it up. Even though it works, I'm sure it's badly coded and doesn't follow best practice. I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Here is how the click event looks now with two additional arguments (test1 and test2) passed to fakeFloat with values of index1 and index2:

```
$("#swapTrigger").click(function()
{
var index1 = $('input:radio[name=index1]:checked').val();
var index2 = $('input:radio[name=index2]:checked').val();
boxes = $(boxes).swap(index1,index2);

var $box1 = $('.box').eq(index1);
var $box2 = $('.box').eq(index2);

var randomHex = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);

$box1.animate({ backgroundColor: randomHex }, 300);
$box2.animate({ backgroundColor: randomHex }, 300);

$(boxes).fakeFloat({margin: 10, offset: 20, speed: 300, test1: index2, test2: index1}).each(function()
{
    $(this).html($(this).getIndexOf(boxes));
});
});
```

and here is the amended fakeFloat method which now contains a background color variable which, via an if-else statement within the each statement, is set depending on whether test1 or test2 are equal to i. Background color animation is added to the position animation. I've initialised test1 and test2 with -1 rather than 0 because i=0 which would cause an unwanted an unwanted animation on load.

```
jQuery.fn.fakeFloat = function(options, callback)
{

var defaults = {
direction: "left",
margin: 0,
offset: 0,
speed: 0,
test1: -1,
test2: -1
},
settings = jQuery.extend({}, defaults, options);  

//Initialize counter
var i=0;

//Default background color
var bg = "#fff";

//Initialize element width
var elemWidth = 0;

jQuery(this).each(function()
{
    if (settings.test1 == i || settings.test2 == i) {
        bg = "#fc0";
    }
    else
    {
        bg = "#fff";
    }

    elemWidth = jQuery(this).width();
    if(settings.direction == "left")
    {
        jQuery(this).animate({"backgroundColor": bg}, 300);
        jQuery(this).animate({"left": ((settings.margin) + elemWidth)*i + (settings.offset) + 'px'}, settings.speed);
        jQuery(this).animate({"backgroundColor": "#fff"}, 300);         }
    else
    {
            jQuery(this).animate({"right": ((settings.margin) + elemWidth)*i + (settings.offset) + 'px'}, settings.speed);
    }
    i++;
});

if(typeof callback == 'function')
{
    setTimeout(function(){callback.call(this);}, settings.speed);
}

return this;

};
```